# php imagettftext load from memory

Tags: php, fonts

the php gd imagettftext function can only load true type fonts from a file.  Is there a way that I can load it in from memory?  For example I pull the file from a DB and pass the string of bytes into it somehow?

Only other option I can think of is to load the file from the db, write it to disk (if it doesn't already exist), and then load it /w imagettftext.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Why can't you save the fonts to the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temp file sounds like a pretty sound idea however I question why you would want to store it in a database.  It's going to be far more efficient to store all those TTF's in a directory somewhere.  I would then just store the path/filename.  That many temporary operations to write the temp files to disk could have some considerable negative effects in a high load environment.

Comment: I'm storing in a DB for convenience. It's easier to do backups, and when those files are attached to other data it's easier to keep it consistent.  I've decided I will setup a cache.  It will check for the file on disk, if not it will load it out of the db and permanently store it on the filesystem.  Future calls will just load it off the FS.  And if I need to migrate to another server I just have a single place that needs to be backed up (everything else is under a configuration management system).

Comment: Sounds like a solid approach.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to store all binary files on the filesystem and store paths to those files on database. Database is not a place for binary files.

Comment: I don't like this because it's possible to lose the files on disk, and then all you have is a path in the database to a non-existant file. It also make it more difficult to setup a mirror.Generally speaking it may not be a good idea to store binary files in a db, but given my circumstances and requirements I believe it's the best route.

Comment: @rizen: Exactly, I went throught the same experience myself and came to the same conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are forced to read from the file system with GD. Even implementing a custom stream wrapper didn't help; GD evidently doesn't make use of PHP's stream system and simply loads the file itself.

What you may want to do is use another language with an image processing library that can accomplish what you need. You will be able to serve up your web pages using PHP and serve up your images using something else.

Comment: That seems to be the case - I concur.